# How to turn off repeated response filter for my chatterbot

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot, chatterbot

I am working on making a chatbot with the chatterbot library in python and it was sometimes not responding correctly, I turned on logging and found that it was because it was excluding responses that it recently used and then defaulted to the "unknown" response I have set.
You can see an excerpt from the logs below:
User: hi

> INFO:chatterbot.chatterbot:Beginning search for close text match
> INFO:chatterbot.chatterbot:Processing search results
> INFO:chatterbot.chatterbot:Similar text found: Hi 1.0
> INFO:chatterbot.chatterbot:Using "Hi" as a close match to "hi" with a confidence of 1.0
> INFO:chatterbot.chatterbot:0. Excluding recent repeated response of "hi"
> INFO:chatterbot.chatterbot:1. Excluding recent repeated response of "Hi there, I am Minerva, how can I help you?"
> INFO:chatterbot.chatterbot:No responses found. Generating alternate response list.

I found out about the recent response filter in the documentation [here](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html) but there is no explanation of how to turn it off or disable it, it is on by default as I have no filters specified in my chatbot code.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to remove the filter? I don't care if my chatbot repeats itself over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there's any configuration to turn off this feature, because it's hardcoded in the [BestMatch logic adapter](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/4ff8af28567ed446ae796d37c246bb6a14032fe7/chatterbot/logic/best_match.py#L49):

```
class BestMatch(LogicAdapter):
    def process(self, input_statement, additional_response_selection_parameters=None):
        ...
        recent_repeated_responses = filters.get_recent_repeated_responses(
            self.chatbot,
            input_statement.conversation
        )
        
        for index, recent_repeated_response in enumerate(recent_repeated_responses):
            self.chatbot.logger.info('{}. Excluding recent repeated response of "{}"'.format(
                index, recent_repeated_response
            ))
        ...
```

And the [`filters.get_recent_repeated_responses`](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/4ff8af28567ed446ae796d37c246bb6a14032fe7/chatterbot/filters.py#L1) function doesn't provide a way to turn it off either:

```
def get_recent_repeated_responses(chatbot, conversation, sample=10, threshold=3, quantity=3):
    """
    A filter that eliminates possibly repetitive responses to prevent
    a chat bot from repeating statements that it has recently said.
    """
    from collections import Counter

    # Get the most recent statements from the conversation
    conversation_statements = list(chatbot.storage.filter(
        conversation=conversation,
        order_by=['id']
    ))[sample * -1:]

    text_of_recent_responses = [
        statement.text for statement in conversation_statements
    ]

    counter = Counter(text_of_recent_responses)

    # Find the n most common responses from the conversation
    most_common = counter.most_common(quantity)

    return [
        counted[0] for counted in most_common
        if counted[1] >= threshold
    ]
```

---

I can think of two ways to get around it:

Create a copy of the logic adapter [BestMatch](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/4ff8af28567ed446ae796d37c246bb6a14032fe7/chatterbot/logic/best_match.py#L49) without the offending lines and specifying it during setup:

```
from chatterbot.logic import LogicAdapter
class BestMatchWithRepetitions(BestMatch):
    def process(self, input_statement, additional_response_selection_parameters=None):
        ...

chatbot = ChatBot(
    "My ChatterBot",
    logic_adapters=[
        # Untested, might need to specify it in another way.
        "BestMatchWithRepetitions"
    ]
)
```

Or, for a very hacky solution, you can monkey-patch the filters package:

```
from chatterbot import filters
filters.get_recent_repeated_responses = lambda *args, **kwargs: []
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I implemented the monkey-patch solution quickly and that seems to work perfectly, so thank you very much.
I might try and override the best match function later and test how that works.